# Expect method call and proxy to original method with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd, controllers

I want to discover with BDD missing :include params for ActiveRecord::Base.find method. So my idea is to have in spec something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.should_receive(:find).once.and_proxy_to_original_method
parent = SomeClass.find 34
parent.child.should be_loaded
parent.other_children.should be_loaded
```

If #child or #other_children associations are not eager loaded, expectation should fail with something like:
"Expected ActiveRecord::Base.find to be invoked once but it was invoked 2 more times with following args: 1. ...; 2. ..."

Does anyone know if there's some matcher that works like this or how to make this.

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue. Really wish there was one. Useful for testing if valid? was invoked on a dependent model or something to ensure the hierarchy is validated/saved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a less intrusive alternative to Rspec's \`should\_receive\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159536/is-there-a-less-intrusive-alternative-to-rspecs-should-receive)

Answer (score 5):

I *think* I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206453/rspec-2-detect-call-to-method-but-still-have-it-perform-its-function/7232418#7232418). In your particular case I would do this which I find quite clean.

```
original_method = ActiveRecord::Base.method(:find)
ActiveRecord::Base.should_receive(:find).once do (*args)
  original_method.call(*args)
end
```

I believe you could extend the Rspec `Mocks::MessageExpectation` class to include the `and_proxy_to_original_method` method, shouldn't be too hard, but I haven't looked.

Comment: Hmmm ... I like the idea. Will check that and come back with result. Thanks