# rspec 2: detect call to method but still have it perform its function

Tags: rspec2

I want to check if a method was called exactly(n) times, *but* I still want that method to perform its original function. Consider a simple thumbnailing system that caches the thumbnail file and make sure ImageMagick's "convert" executable that creates the thumbnail is only called on the first request.

```
  it "this passes: should detect a cached version" do
    thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url_for("images/something.jpg")
    get thumbnail_url
    last_response.should be_ok
    Sinatra::Thumbnail.should_not_receive(:convert)
    get thumbnail_url
    last_response.should be_ok
  end

  it "this fails:  should detect a cached version" do
    Sinatra::Thumbnail.should_receive(:convert).exactly(1).times
    thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url_for("images/something.jpg")
    get thumbnail_url
    last_response.should be_ok
    get thumbnail_url
    last_response.should be_ok
 end
```

In my case I get away with my first attempt, but there could be cases where I don't. The second one fails because the call `Thumbnail.convert` is detected but the method itself doesn't do anything. Is there some way to just detect the call to the method and have it do it's original thing?

BTW: I suspect this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320292/expect-method-call-and-proxy-to-original-method-with-rspec) is very similar, but then I get lost in the description and also it's unanswered...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now there's an `and_call_original` method precisely for this use case.  (RSpec 2.12)

```
Sinatra::Thumbnails.should_receive(:convert).and_call_original
```

The documentation can be found on the same page referenced by Joao, [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/message-expectations).

See also: the [changelog](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/changelog)

Answer (score 15):

Yay! I think I figured it out!

```
it "should detect a cached version" do
  original_method = Sinatra::Thumbnails.method(:convert)
  Sinatra::Thumbnails.should_receive(:convert).exactly(1).times do |*args|
    original_method.call(*args)
  end
  thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url_for("images/something.jpg") # 
  get thumbnail_url
  last_response.should be_ok
  get thumbnail_url
  last_response.should be_ok
end
```

It's documented (poorly, in my opinion) in [here](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/message-expectations) at the very end...

Comment: the documentation is indeed poor, and I can't find any mentioning of `original_method` in the page you pointed to. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: `original_method` is just a local variable I used! The page I linked to mentions "arbitrary handling", which is what I needed to call the method stored in that local variable.

Comment: This answer is out of date. See @kpassa615's answer.

Comment: Ok, updated the accepted answer since rspec caught up. Downvoting was slightly mean though...