# Set an expectation without mocking anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stub, mocha.js, expectations

Using MiniTest::Spec and Mocha:

```
 describe "#devices" do
   it "scopes the devices by the provided :ip_list" do
     ips = 'fast tests ftw!'
     ds = DeviceSearch.new ip_list: ips
     Device.expects(:scope_by_ip_list).once.with(ips)
     ds.devices
   end
 end
```

When I make the code work correctly, this test will fail, because calling `Device.expects(:scope_by_ip_list)` also *stubs* `Device.scope_by_ip_list`, and since I don't specify a `.returns(Devices.scoped)` or some such, it stubs out the method with `nil`. So, in my code which properly scopes a list of devices and then does further operations, the further operations blow up.

I don't *want* to have to specify a `.returns` parameter, though, because I totally don't care what it returns. I don't want to stub the method at all! I just want to set up an expectation on it, and leave it functioning just the way it is.

Is there a way to do that?

(To me, it seems very awkward to say something like `Device.expects(:foo).returns('bar')`—when I say that `Model` **expects** `method`, I'm **not** saying to **stub** that method! We can say `Device.stubs(:foo)`, if we want to stub it.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby Mocha: is there an equivalent to rspec-mocks' #and\_call\_original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715174/ruby-mocha-is-there-an-equivalent-to-rspec-mocks-and-call-original)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is intended and can't be changed. Look at the following post to see how it can be circumwented:

[rspec 2: detect call to method but still have it perform its function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206453/rspec-2-detect-call-to-method-but-still-have-it-perform-its-function)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link! However, I am using Minitest and doing the stubbing/expectations with Mocha, so the RSpec example is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I overlooked that. Sorry for that.