# Ruby Mocha: is there an equivalent to rspec-mocks' #and_call_original?

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

Rspec-mocks has `expect(some_object).to receive(:some_method).and_call_original`. Can I do this with Mocha, and if so, how? `some_object.expects(:some_method)....` ...what?

Comment: To help searchers find this page: What's being asked for here is called a `spy` in some other mocking frameworks.  See e.g. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies

Answer (score 14):

I'm fairly sure that there isn't a way to do this.

Looking through the [source code](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha/object_methods.rb#L38), there's a comment that mentions that the original method is completely replaced.

```
# The original implementation of the method is replaced during the test and then restored at the end of the test. The temporary replacement method has the same visibility as the original method.
```