# Mocha. expects without stubbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-mocha

I there something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206453/rspec-2-detect-call-to-method-but-still-have-it-perform-its-function) for Mocha.

I have this:

```
reservation.expects(:publish_to_sns).twice
reservation.save
reservation.update_attribute :first => 'qweqwe'
```

And I would like `publish_to_sns` to  perform its function.