# Is there a less intrusive alternative to Rspec's `should_receive`?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In writing Rspec tests, I'm often frustrated with `should_receive`. I'd like to know if there's a less intrusive alternative.

For example:

```
describe "making a cake" do
  it "should use some other methods" do
    @baker.should_receive(:make_batter)
    @baker.make_cake
  end
end
```

The call to `should_receive` is a good description, but it breaks my code, because `should_receive` works by masking the original method, and `make_cake` can't proceed unless `make_batter` actually returns some batter. So I change it to this:

```
@baker.should_receive(:make_batter).and_return(@batter)
```

This is ugly because:

- It **looks** like I'm testing that `make_batter` correctly returns `@batter`, but I'm **actually** forcing the fake version of `make_batter` to return that.
- It forces me to separately set up `@batter`
- If `make_batter` has any important side effects (which could be a code smell, I suppose) I have to make those happen, too.

I wish that `should_receive(:make_batter)` would verify the method call and **pass it on to the original method**. If I wanted to stub its behavior for better isolation testing, I would do so explicitly: `@baker.stub(:make_batter).and_return(@batter)`.

Is there a way to do something like `should_receive` without preventing the original method call? Is my problem a symptom of bad design?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It looks like the nicer API to delegate to the original method that Myron Marston alluded to has actually been added in [rspec-mocks v2.12.0](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/compare/v2.11.3...v2.12.0)

- [Add `and_call_original` which delegates to the original method.](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/2ab27764bdcadac77534e5a9a5937c3d3bece422)

So now you can simply do this any time you "want to set a message expecation without interfering with how the object responds to the message":

```
@baker.should_receive(:make_batter).and_call_original
```

Thanks for adding this, Myron.

Comment: And thank *you* for revisiting this question with an updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can have `should_receive` run the original method like so:

```
@baker.should_receive(:make_batter, &@baker.method(:make_batter))
```

Both `should_receive` and `stub` support passing a block implementation (that is eval'd when the method is called). `&@baker.method(:make_batter)` gets a handle to the original method object, and passes it along as the block implementation.

FWIW, we'd like to provide a nicer API to delegate to the original method (see [this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/23)), but it's difficult to add that functionality without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Neat! I didn't realize `should_receive` could take a block. Also good to see that I'm not the only one who wants this.

Comment: Alternate (possibly unworkable) idea: what if, in my example, the test simply bailed from `bake_cake` once `make_batter` had been received? I shouldn't be testing more than one thing at a time anyway, right?

Comment: I created a little helper method for this: `def should_receive_and_proceed(object, method); object.should_receive(method, &object.method(method)); end`

Comment: Given it is 2016 now, I think @Tyler Rick's answer above is more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14693779/224707

Answer (score 6):

You're having this problem with `should_receive` because you're testing implementation details of the `make_cake` method. When writing tests you should only focus on behavior and not on a sequence of internal method calls. Otherwise refactoring your code later would result in a huge refactoring of all your tests as well.

Mocks and Stubs come in handy when you want to test your classes in isolation. When writing unit tests your test subject should be isolated from any other object. Both act as a stand-in when you're working with multiple objects at once. In this case you can use `should_receive` to ensure that your test subject correctly delegates some task to another object by calling a method.

Comment: Your overall point about not testing implementation details feels correct, but it seems that's the only use case for `should_receive`, right? I'm still unclear how `should_receive(:foo)` can be used at all without `and_return` if `foo` is supposed to return something.

Comment: Also, probably my lousy example obscures the issue. Suppose I've written a wrapper method for some library. I want to test that my wrapper calls the underlying library method with the correct arguments, and my method also needs to parse what it gets back before returning. I think that puts me back to `some_library.should_receive(:some_method).with('foo', 'bar').and_return('thingy')`, right? In this case, I'm not testing an implementation detail, but the purpose of the wrapper method.

Comment: In this case you of course want to return something. But in order to keep up the isolation I'd fake the return value from the library. (A good example would be a library that wraps a web service. I wouldn't want my tests to call out for the web service every time I run them and I don't want to rely on all the parts that could go wrong during a call to it) That's of course something I'd only do in unit tests. When writing integration tests I'd want all levels of the implementation the be triggered.