# How do I deal with rspec should_receive replacing the method when I want the method to actually be executed?

Tags: rspec, expectations

I'm new to using rspec should_receive and having a lot of problems because it "replaces" the method. For example:

```
UserMailer.should_receive(:new_order).with(order)
```

gives undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass, since rspec makes the method stop working. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deal with this by adding `.and_call_original` to your method chain as follows:

```
UserMailer.should_receive(:new_order).with(order).and_call_original
```

as documented in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method and discussed in [Is there a less intrusive alternative to Rspec's `should_receive`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159536/is-there-a-less-intrusive-alternative-to-rspecs-should-receive)