# Why is this Ruby conditional assignment not memoized?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can someone explain why this spec is failing?

**RSpec results:**

```
User#presenter memoizes presenter
     Failure/Error: user.presenter
       (<UserPresenter (class)>).new(...)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 2 times with arguments: (...)
```

From my understanding of the conditional assignment operator it should only assign `@presenter` once.

```
 # app/models/user.rb
def User
    def presenter
        @presenter ||= UserPresenter.new(self)
    end
end 

# app/presenters/user_presenter.rb
class UserPresenter
end

# spec/models/user_spec.rb
describe User do

    let(:user){ build_stubbed(:user) }

    describe "#presenter" do
        it "memoizes presenter" do
            UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once
            user.presenter
            user.presenter # should not call .new
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: why not `UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once.with(...)` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit does not change anything `received: 2 times with arguments...` although it might be a good idea to test that it is called with the correct argument.

Comment: Can you do `let!(:user){ build_stubbed(:user) }` and `UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once.with(user)` ?

Comment: Failure/Error: user.presenter
       (<UserPresenter (class)>).new(#<User _id: 537761456d617817981e0000>)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (#<User _id: 537761456d617817981e0000>)
           received: 2 times with arguments: (#<User _id: 537761456d617817981e0000>)

Comment: Please join - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53879/ruby-rails

Comment: Edit: Changed def UserPresenter to class UserPresenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once
```

This chunk of code simply sets up the expectation that a `UserPresenter` will receive the `new` method one time. It tears down your original `UserPresenter#new` method and replaces it with a method that returns `nil`. Because `nil` is falsy, the `@presenter` instance variable is not memoized.

To fix this, you can specify a return value in your expectation:

```
UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once.and_return "some truthy value"
```

or equivalently

```
UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once { "some truthy value" }
```

or if you absolutely want to call the original method

```
UserPresenter.should_receive(:new).once.and_call_original
```

or with the new expect syntax

```
expect(UserPresenter).to receive(:new).once.and_call_original
```

See [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations) for more information about expecting a message, and [this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method) for more information about calling the original method. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159536/is-there-a-less-intrusive-alternative-to-rspecs-should-receive) has some further discussion about RSpec's `should_receive` method.