# Rspec2: expect a few arguments among many to be called

Tags: unit-testing, activerecord, rspec, rspec2

I need to test that a piece of code executes two sql statements, which I'm doing by saying

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with("s1")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with("s2")
```

However, the code also executes a lot of other statements that I don't care about, which trips up the test. How do I tell Rspec to make sure that `s1` and `s2` are in the list of executed statements?

Comment: `"which trips up the test"` -- do you mean that this makes the expectations not work, or do you mean that it makes the actual code not work?

Comment: The expectations don't work - there are a few queries that are executed  before and after `s1` and `s2` that trigger an expectation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version of RSpec to 2.12 and you will have access to the `and_call_original` method (see the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames#Delegating_to_the_Original_Implementation) and [use cases](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method)). Using that method, you can stub the `execute` method of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` and make it call through to the original method, and then just add to that the expectations you want:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.stub(:execute).and_call_original
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with(:s1)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with(:s2)
```

If for whatever reason you are not using (or don't want to use) the latest version of RSpec, you can achieve the same functionality this way:

```
execute = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.method(:execute)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with(:s1)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).with(:s2)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.stub(:execute) { |*args| execute.call(*args) }
```

Refs:

- [rspec 2: detect call to method but still have it perform its function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206453/rspec-2-detect-call-to-method-but-still-have-it-perform-its-function)
- [Expect method call and proxy to original method with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320292/expect-method-call-and-proxy-to-original-method-with-rspec)

Comment: Damn. I'm sure this answer is correct, but I find it odd that something this simple would be this difficult.

Comment: Updated my answer. I was confused about version numbers, 2.12 is higher than 2.8 so all you have to do is update your version to get access to `and_call_original`. Once you do that, it's just a matter of adding one line: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.stub(:execute).and_call_original` which will catch all cases, and you can set your expectations without any concern about disrupting the normal flow.